# Checking if a String doesn't contain any symbols without adding a bunch of checks (java)

Tags: java

What the title says. I want to know if there something in the JDK that already has that where i could return false if the string contained any symbols such as *, #, @, & etc without needing to add a single contain check for every one of those. thanks.

Comment: An array of the bad symbols, loop through and check: `String[] s = {"@", "*"}; for (String a : s) if (x.contains(s)) ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could whitelist characters in a [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) call:

```
!string.matches("[^A-Za-z]")  // only alpha characters
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for regular expressions, that's quite complex if you don't know them
but a quick way to do what you want would be:
`"somestring".matches("\\*#@&")`